# How do you experimentally realise the operator of the form $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, quantum-measurements, anticommutator

I was reading a paper in which the authors use the operator of the form $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$  and it is implied to be experimentally realisable. 
(i.e either creating an apparatus to measure this operator or/and using some method to calculate the expectation value)

My question is about how in general this operator be experimentally realised in terms of some combination of measurements of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ where $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are hermitian operators that are measurable?

Edit:

If $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute we can calculate the $<\hat{A}\hat{B}>$ by just multiplying the measurements of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ and then taking the average value.

Therefore my question reduces to non- commuting observables only.

Comment: What do you mean by “realisable”?

Comment: @knzhou any operator which can be measured through a physical apparatus, like Sz spin operator through the stern gerlach experiment.

Comment: So by "realisable" you just mean "measurable"?

Comment: @knzhou I think I unnecessarily complicated the language. Yes, I meant measurable. But I would also like to know the ways you can measure the expectation value of AB+BA, and not just construction of the apparatus AB+BA.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: There is also some non-commuting cases there $AB+BA$ is easy to measure.

Answer (score 8):

> My question is about how in general this operator be experimentally realisable in terms of some combination of measurements of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ where $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are hermitian operators that are experimentally realisable?

There is no reason to believe that a measurement of $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$ can be realized as a combination of the measurements of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ unless, of course, $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$.

If the two operators commute, you can simply measure one and then the other. The measurement of $\hat{B}$ won't take the state out of the eigensubspace of $\hat{A}$ into which it was projected as a result of the measurement of $\hat{A}$ and thus, you can simultaneously measure both, and thus, any combination thereof.

However, if the two operators don't commute, you cannot measure something like $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{A}\hat{B}$ using only the measurement of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ for they simply cannot be measured simultaneously (as they don't share an eigenbasis).

Notice that the formalism of quantum mechanics as such allows for the measurement of any Hermitian operator but it might be incredibly complex to actually measure some arbitrarily cooked up Hermitian operator. Physically meaningful operators are almost always the ones associated with symmetries.

---

Of course, if you have a large number of copies of the state, you can simply deduce the wavefunction of the state using observations of a tomographically complete set of observables and then you can calculate the expectation value of the operator $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$ over the given state without needing to actually measure it. However, if you're interested in actually measuring the state and collapsing it to one of the eigenstates of $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$, you have to build a clever enough experiment to do so if $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\neq 0$.

---

**Important Point Raised by** `@NorbertSchuch`

Even in the case when $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute, while it is true that (twice) the product of the eigenvalues obtained by the measurement of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ would give the same eigenvalue as the measurement of $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$ would give on the same state, it's not necessary that the post-measurement state would be the same.

To steal the nice example that `@NorbertSchuch` provided in the comment, consider the state $\left\vert\uparrow\uparrow\right\rangle+\left|\downarrow\downarrow\right\rangle$. A measurement of $\hat{\sigma}_z\otimes\hat{\sigma}_z$ would give the eigenvalue $1$ and the post-measurement state would simply remain $|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle+|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle$ as it is an eigenstate of $\hat{\sigma}_z\otimes\hat{\sigma}_z$. However, if you make the simultaneous measurements of $\hat{\sigma}_z\otimes\hat{\mathbb{I}}$ and  $\hat{\mathbb{I}}\otimes\hat{\sigma}_z$ then the resulting state would be either $|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle$ or $|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle$. Notice that in either case, we would still get the product of the eigenvalues to be $1$ in agreement with the direct measurement of $\hat{\sigma}_z\otimes\hat{\sigma}_z$.

Comment: Thanks! As I got from your answer, I think there are two ways to go about measuring, collapsing it to an eigenstate as an individual measurement or measuring the expectation value in which you mentioned tomographically complete operators. Can you please elaborate a bit on the latter?

Comment: @netflix_and_physics, if you know the Hamiltonian of the system then you can find out what all operators commute with it. Then finding expectation of each of these operators will give you information about the state you’re measuring. Of course this means you must be able to make the same state as many times as needed. However, there’s also a way in which the wavefunction can directly be mapped called molecular orbital tomography. https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2029

Comment: Note that even if the operators commute, you have *not* implemented the same measurement, if you also care about the post-measurement state.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thank you for your comment. Can you say a bit more as to why? I hadn't thought about it but I suppose for example, if $AB$ is degenerate in a way such that the eigensubspace of one of its degenerate eigenvalues is not degenerate w.r.t. $A$ and $B$ then a direct measurement of $AB$ would preserve the relative phases of the original state's component along the eigensubspace. But measurements of $A$ and $B$ would not. Is this in the right direction?

Comment: Imagine you have two spins and can measure either of them in the $z$ direction.  Now take the state $\left\vert\uparrow\uparrow\right\rangle+ \left\vert\downarrow\downarrow\right\rangle$.  If you measure $\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z$, you find that both spins point in the same direction, without affecting the state.  On the other hand, if you measure $\sigma_z$ on the two spins individually, you also learn that they point in the same direction (same measurement), but the post-measurement state is either $\left\vert\uparrow\uparrow\right\rangle$ or $\left\vert\downarrow\downarrow\right\rangle$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Many thanks for the beautiful example! :) I have added this point to my answer. If you want to post it as an answer, I'd be more than happy to remove that part from my answer. I just thought it's too crucial a point to be left in the comments for only some of the readers to find.

Comment: Feel free to steal it.  I suggested some aesthetic corrections in the latex ;)

Answer (score 1):

The smallest explicit example I could come up with where this can be done for sure, a bit silly maybe: let

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\ \ \ \ \ B = \begin{pmatrix}1&-i\\i&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $A$ and $B$ don't commute, and

$$AB + BA = \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}.$$

This means that you can just measure $A$ and multiply the result by 2 to get a measurement of $AB + BA$.

If you want to realize this physically, you could for example interpret these as measuring the spin of a spin 1/2 particle in the usual basis. Then $A$ measures (a fixed multiple $2/\hbar$ of) the spin in $z$-direction, and $B$ measures a different function of spin in $y$-direction, namely 0 for up and 2 for down.

Their anticommutator measures $4/\hbar$ times the spin in $z$-direction, so you could just change the configuration file of the device measuring spin in $z$-direction.

Comment: $A=\sigma_x$ and $B=\sigma_z$ is an even simpler (and sillier!) example.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Haha, yes!

Comment: Since the anti-commutator of the Pauli matrices vanish, and the Pauli matrices (and identity matrix) are complete basis for hermitian operators for 2 dimensional systems, can there exist a way to generalise this result and create method to measure AB + BA in general?

Comment: @netflix_and_physics I doubt that - note that in my example, you don't have to do a measurement at all to "measure" AB+BA.  For instance, there will be no way to measure the Y expectation value if you can only measure the X and Z expectation value.  Just imagine both are zero - you can't know which of the two Y eigenstates you have. --  Basically, you measure (even if you can measure repeatedly!) only the projection of the state on the XZ plane, so you can learn nothing about the component outside that plane (unless, of course, you are at the boundary of the Bloch sphere projection).

Answer (score 0):

Such quantities are measured more frequently than it may seem: indeed, any *real* (i.e. measurable) correlation function of two non-commuting quantities is given by
$$K(t, t_1) = \langle \frac{1}{2}\left[\hat{A}(t), \hat{B}(t_1)\right]_+\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\left[
\langle\hat{A}(t)\hat{B}(t_1)\rangle + \langle\hat{B}(t_1)\hat{A}(t)\rangle\right], 
$$
which is routinely measured in experiments, e.g., in spin resonance.
Even when this quantity is not measured directly, it is easily obtained via the response function (aka susceptibility)
$$\varphi(t, t_1) = \langle \frac{i}{\hbar}\left[\hat{A}(t), \hat{B}(t_1)\right]_-\rangle,$$
to which it is related via the [fluctuation-dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem)
$$K(\omega)=\hbar\coth\left(\frac{\hbar\omega}{k_BT}\right)Im\varphi(\omega).$$

Comment: But here, A and B usually commute.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide some resource or explain in brief how the correlation function is measured?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Note that my $A, B$ are different from those in the question. They certainly do not commute, since this would mean that the susceptibility is identically zero. *They might commute at the same time* - and such combinations are often preferred, because they facilitate calculations - e.g., the Kubo formula is much easier to deal with when expressed as a current-current correlation function, which however requires using a time-dependent gauge. Even then one may have to deal with non-diagonal susceptibilities, e.g., in the case of Hall effect.

Comment: @Vadim Fair point, my fault.

Answer (score -2):

Some physical quantities such as energy, momentum, position, are associated with corresponding operators. It does not follow that arbitrary operators have a meaningful physical quantity associated with them.

If A, B do not commute, it is likely that measurement of A prevents simultaneous measurement of B. For example, measurement of position prevents simultaneous measurement of momentum. Operator $\hat{x}\hat{p}_x$ is not associated with any common useful physical quantity and there is no common way to measure it.

Comment: I see your point, but $\hat{x}\hat{p}_x$ isn't a hermitian operator at all and hence can't be measured, but the operator I mentioned is hermitian.

Comment: @netflixandphysics True but what Jan said is also true of xp+px.

Comment: @netflix_and_physics the operator you mentioned is symmetric, but there is no requirement for it to correspond to any useful physical quantity that can be measured.

Comment: Just because something "does not correspond to a useful physical" quantity, it does not mean it cannot be measured.  I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch it answers it in negative. There is infinity of symmetric operators that have no known relation to any established physical quantity with a known way to measure it. $xp_x+p_xx$ is a symmetric operator, nothing more.

Comment: If it is hermitian and bounded, there is no reason in the laws of quantum mechanics, there is no reason why we should not be able to measure it, except lack of imagination.

Comment: Symmetric operators are the map, not the territory. Some maps are useful and connected to the real thing, some are not. It is unlikely to find a meaningful physical quantity and measurement method for it, associated with operators such as $xp_x + p_xx$. Or $p_x/x + x/p_x$ or $L_xL_y+L_yL_x$. Not impossible, but unlikely.